# How To Change a Popup Window's Location

Tags: javascript, html

I have a popup window being opened by my application as follows:

```
function newPopup(url, windowName) {
    window.open(url,windowName,'height=768,width=1366,left=10,top=10,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
}
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('lobby.do', 'lobby');">Enter Lobby</a>
```

Inside that popup window, I want the user to have the ability to move that popup's window location by clicking a link:

```
<a href="game.do">New Game</a>
```

However, when click this link in the popup window, the popup is automatically closed and the redirect does not happen.  I've tried adding an onClick and using javaScript:window.location, but get the same results.  Any idea what could be causing this?  I've tested in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: So is this link in the main page or in the pop up window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set the `target` of the link to the popup's name.

```
<a href="game.do" target="lobby">New Game</a>
```

Or save the value returned from `window.open` and set its `.location`.

```
function newPopup(url, windowName) {
    return window.open(url,windowName,'height=768,width=1366,left=10,top=10,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no');
}

<a onclick="window.lobby=newPopup('lobby.do', 'lobby'); return false;" href="#">Enter Lobby</a>
<a href="window.lobby.location='game.do'; return false;" href="#">New Game</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do to open it in a new window is add `target_blank` at the end of a `html` link like this:

```html
<a href="http://link-to-your-game" target="_blank">Enter Lobby</a>
```

Comment: don't know why my examle won't show  it's <a href="http://link-to-your-game" target="_blank">Enter Lobby</a>

Comment: I may end up needing to go with this route, but I am hoping to not have to.  I want to keep both the lobby and the game at this predefined window size, so using a popup seems to be the best route.  I'm just not sure why the popup is being closed instead of being redirected to my desired page.

Answer (score 0):

why not to use ajax:

`<a onclick="ajaxcall_to_newpage()"> click here to update the content </a>`

and your ajax function requesting a new content from server and rendering it to html:

```
..
}).done(function(data){
   $('#your_div_of_pop_up').text(data);
});
```

job is done!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you need is to name your popup.  Then you can reference that popup to change the content of it.

All you need is a bit of `JavaScript`

```js
function createPopup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'testWindow','height=800,width=600');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
```

That can be used like this :

```html
<a href="#" onclick="createPopup('http://www.google.com')" target="mine">use google</a>
<a href="#" onclick="createPopup('http://www.stackoverflow.com')" target="mine">use stackoverflow</a>
```

So from the *main* window you can control your popup.